# In spray for scala, get a FromRequestUnmarshaller from an ordinary Unmarshaller

Tags: scala, spray

In scala spray, is there a way to convert from a `Unmarshaller[T]` to a `FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]`. I'm stuck trying to make the `entity` directive work without using implicits. For example:

```
...
} ~ post {
  path("myPath") {
    entity(sprayJsonUnmarshaller[MyCaseClass](myCaseClassRootJsonFormat)) { myCaseClass =>
      complete { handle(myCaseClass) }
    }
  } ~ ...
```

Compiler error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - type mismatch; found : spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller[MyCaseClass] (which 
     expands to) spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[spray.http.HttpEntity,MyCaseClass] 
     required: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[?] (which expands to) 
     spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[spray.http.HttpRequest,?]
    - type mismatch; found : spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller[MyCaseClass] (which 
     expands to) spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[spray.http.HttpEntity,MyCaseClass] 
     required: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[?] (which expands to) 
     spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[spray.http.HttpRequest,?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part Spray is heavily depends on implicit resolution. I might be not correct, but as i know there is now simple and elegant way to do this. Like it was designed you should you the following directive: `entity(as[MyCaseClass])`. Then, if you take a look at `as[_]` directive, there is not a short way to make a simple unmarshaller (which takes an entity and makes your case class) to fromRequestUnmarshaller (from HttpRequest -> case class), all implicit expanders can be found [here] (https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/unmarshalling/UnmarshallerLifting.scala#L21). So when you are calling `entity(as[MyCaseClass])` it expands to this:

```
entity {
  as[MyCaseClass] {
    fromRequestUnmarshaller[MyCaseClass] {
      fromMessageUnmarshaller[MyCaseClass] {
        sprayJsonUnmarshaller[MyCaseClass](myCaseClassRootJsonFormat)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to make it explicit, then you should write it in the upper form. In this way you can drop `as[MyCaseClass]`

On the other hand you may choose the other explicit way - extract entity and convert it to json:

```
requestInstance { req =>
  val json = req.entity.asString.parseJson
  json.convertTo(myCaseClassRootJsonFormat)
}
```

Comment: I also made a `FromRequestUnmarshaller` as follows: `def unmarshaller[T](fmt: JsonFormat[T]): FromRequestUnmarshaller[T] = {
    val f: HttpRequest => T = hr => fmt.read(hr.entity.asString)
    Deserializer.fromFunction2Converter[HttpRequest, T](f)
  }`